# Spring data last record

Tags: java, spring-data, hql

I have entity `Invoice`. And I need get `paymentDate` of Invoice, but just of last record in database. How to do it using `@Query`? HQL doesn't support `last` query.

Comment: what is the last record?  Is it sorted?  Maybe sorted the other way and get the first record/

Comment: @ScaryWombat well, I can write query like: 'select i.paymentDate from Invoice i where i.id = ?1 order by i.paymentDate desc' but it return me all records. How I can get only one? In this example how I can get only first record?

Comment: If you are querying using an `id` then it should return a unique record

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry, it was bad example. I'm querying using an 'organizerId'

Answer (score 0):

To get a singleresult from a query try

```
// construct a unique query -- maybe limit 1
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Country c");
long countryCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```